# Dynamic c# compiler in Xamarin.Forms not finding type or namespace

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a Xamarin.Forms app to dynamically compile c# code on a button press, but I get errors in the code.

This is the code for the button being pressed:

```
        {
            string text = ((Editor)sender).Text;
            var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, text);
            results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => string errors = error.ErrorText;
        }
```

and I am using:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
```

With the XAML being this: 
`<Button x:Name="compilebutton" Text="Compile" Clicked="oncompile" />`

```
The type or namespace name 'CompilerParameters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    

The type or namespace name 'CompilerResults' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   

The type or namespace name 'CompilerError' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have tested this without Xamarin.Forms in a Console Application and it worked fine, i'm not sure what the issue is, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: System.CodeDom is not available in .NET Standard

Comment: @Jason Ah, I see. Are there any other ways to dynamically compile c# code in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Apple explicitly prohibits dynamic code generation.

Comment: @Jason Android?

Comment: @Jason Is there a way to do it on Android?

Comment: I don't know.  I just know that Apple specifically prohibits dynamic code.

Comment: @Jason Ah, I see.